# Combine flatMap returning no expected contextual result type

Tags: swift, combine

In *HomeRepositoryImpl* is *getWorldWideData* function which returns *AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType>*

```
func getWorldwideData() -> AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> {
    let url = RestEndpoints.worldwideStats.endpoint()
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> = RestManager().fetchData(url: url)
    
    return publisher
        .flatMap {
            let filteredCountries = Array($0.countries.sorted(by: {$0.totalConfirmed > $1.totalConfirmed}).prefix(3))
            $0.countries = filteredCountries
            return Just($0)
        }
}
```

FlatMap takes *WorldResponseItem* from publisher and *WorldResponseItem* has *countries* array property which I wanted to sort, so I created new variable called *filteredCountries* and changed it value to array with 3 sorted countries, and I changed *WorldResponseItem* countries property to *filteredCountries* and flatMap is returning Just with *WorldResponseItem* from publisher.

But I am getting *No 'flatMap' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType>'* error, and when I add *.eraseToAnyPublisher()* to pipeline, I am getting *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your `flatMap`. You need to call `setFailureType` and `eraseToAnyPublisher` on the `Just` inside the `flatMap` and then also call `eraseToAnyPublisher` on the `flatMap` itself.

You should also use named closure arguments when working with nested closures - you have a `sorted(by:)` nested inside `flatMap`.

```
func getWorldwideData() -> AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> {
    let url = RestEndpoints.worldwideStats.endpoint()
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> = RestManager().fetchData(url: url)

    return publisher
        .flatMap { response -> AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> in
            let filteredCountries = Array(response.countries.sorted(by: { $0.totalConfirmed > $1.totalConfirmed }).prefix(3))
            response.countries = filteredCountries
            return Just(response).setFailureType(to: ErrorType.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

However, you shouldn't be using `flatMap` in the first place. You are just mapping an output to a different value, so you can simply use `map`, which simplifies the closure quite a lot.

```
func getWorldwideData() -> AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> {
    let url = RestEndpoints.worldwideStats.endpoint()
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<WorldwideResponseItem, ErrorType> = RestManager().fetchData(url: url)

    return publisher
        .map { response -> WorldwideResponseItem in
            let filteredCountries = Array(response.countries.sorted(by: { $0.totalConfirmed > $1.totalConfirmed }).prefix(3))
            response.countries = filteredCountries
            return response
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```